# Play Billing - Implement In-app purchase to unlock content and remove ads

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase, play-billing-library

I have a game in which you play 1v1 against friends answering questions. Currently there are 5 sets of questions monetised by admob. I plan to add another 10 sets and the option of forfeits, which will all be unlocked via an in-app purchase (also removes ads).

I have the implementation working, but feel like it's not the best way of doing it and could be exploited by editing `SharedPreferences`.

When a user purchases "premium" via an in-app purchase, I am setting a `"has_premium"` value in `SharedPreferences`. In my fragment's `OnCreateView()` I call `querySkuDetailsAsync()` and update this preference accordingly to make sure all purchases are acknkowledged and up-to-date.

Wherever I have placed ads, I will check this `SharePreference` value and then show/hide ads. Likewise, when displaying the `RecyclerView` of available question sets and forfeits, I again check this `SharePreference` value. If the user is premium, I enable all items in the `RecyclerView`. If the user is not premium, then I disable some items and instead launch the `BillingFlow` when clicked.

Is there a better way of checking that the user has purchased "premium" status than storing the value `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 0):

By moving all billing logic to a `BillingRepository`, which caches purchases in a local database, then serving all fragments which display ads or premium features via a `BillingViewModel`, there is no need for any `SharedPreferences`

I can simply call:

```
billingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BillingViewModel::class.java)
    billingViewModel.userPurchasedProLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.apply {
            showProStatus(entitled)
        }
    })

private fun showProStatus(entitled: Boolean) {
        if (entitled) {
            btnMainMenuPro.visibility = View.GONE
            disableAds()
        } else {
            btnMainMenuPro.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            enableAds()
        }
    }
```

As per the Google Docs:

> Notice that the connection to [playStoreBillingClient] is created
>   using the
>        * applicationContext. This means the instance is not [Activity]-specific. And since it's also
>        * not expensive, it can remain open for the life of the entire [Application]. So whether it is
>        * (re)created for each [Activity] or [Fragment] or is kept open for the life of the application
>        * is a matter of choice.

More info and an example can be found here: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/TrivialDriveKotlin